# ¿Como hacer para hacer funcionar una API para enviar mails automaticaticamente?

Tags: javascript, html, email, fetch

Estoy intentando incorporar una API en una página de promedios para que el usuario ingrese su mail en una seccion y se le envie automaticamente pero no logro hacerlo conectar. Lo tengo que hacer utilzando fetch y lo que tengo hasta ahora es esto

```
document.getElementById('miFormulario').addEventListener('click', async function pedirDatos (){
    const resp = await fetch('https://api.emailjs.com/api/v1.0/email/send')
    
    .then((response) =>{
        console.log(response)
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error)
    })
})
```

Pero en la consola me aparece esto

'promedio.js:80          GET https://api.emailjs.com/api/v1.0/email/send 404
pedirDatos @ promedio.js:80
promedio.js:83 Response {type: 'cors', url: 'https://api.emailjs.com/api/v1.0/email/send', redirected: false, status: 404, ok: false, …}'

y no se manda el correo. Que me estaria faltando para poder hacerlo funcionar?

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 404 significa que esa URL no existe. Es necesario revisar

Comment: Y como podría solucionarlo? El enlace lo saque de la pagina de emailJS, o que otra api se puede utilizar para ese motivo? Gracias por responder!

Comment: Ni idea de dónde sacaste eso porque la [documentación](https://www.emailjs.com/docs/user-guide/connecting-email-services/) dice algo muuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuy diferente.

Comment: Soy muy novato utilizando APIS con fetch y pense que se podia adaptar jaja, entonces si o si hay que utilizar lo de la documentacion?

Comment: Pues la documentación es lo que los amigos de emailJS dicen que toca hacer para usar su servicio. Suena a que intentar usar la API por fuera de los términos puede ser ilegal (y ellos seguro harán lo posible porque no lo hagas sin crear la cuenta...)

Comment: En cualquier caso... te diría que te esfuerces un poquito y te leas la documentación de cómo enviar emails desde emailjs (además de darse de alta, etc., etc.
La tienes en https://www.emailjs.com/docs/rest-api/send/ y al menos ahí dice que hay que utilizar el método POST y los parámetros (mínimos) de service_id, template_id y user_id. Así que... por favor, la próxima vez lee la documentación de lo que sugieres antes de preguntar. Y que el ejemplo que muestras al menos se acerque a lo que te piden